# JavaScript remove duplicate lines from textarea, but keep (ignore) empty lines

Tags: javascript

I use this code:

```
window.removeDuplicateLines = function() {
"use strict";
    var bodyText = $('#text-area').val().split('\n');
    var uniqueText = [];
    $.each(bodyText, function(i, el){
        if($.inArray(el, uniqueText) === -1) {
            uniqueText.push(el);
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('text-area').value = uniqueText.join('\n');
};
```

from here: [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array) to remove duplicate lines from the textarea.

This code works good, but it removes empty lines also as duplicates.

**Question:** How can I remove duplicate lines, but keep (ignore) empty lines, with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to see if the entire line has just spaces. To do so you can **[trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)** and then check if length is `0`. So change your `if` check to below

```
   if($.inArray(el, uniqueText) === -1 || $.trim(el).length === 0) {
        uniqueText.push(el);
    }
```

Comment: @Misha glad I could help!!